# How to send a reminder message to schedule meeting | Linkedin

Tags: professionalism, interviewing, email, linkedin

I am setting up an informational interview with a director of a firm. I approached the person to which they replied that they were happy to read my message and would like to offer me time and asked me for schedule. I replied with a thank you note and told them that i am free on these days but can find time on other days according to your schedule. Note: I am still a student so I can find time between classes. I have waited 7 business days but did not get a reply from her and now I am thinking of writing a polite reminder but I am confused on how to write it.

Following was her reply:

> Good morning Faisal! I enjoyed reading your email this morning and would like to offer up some time for us to chat. Let me know your availability and we can look to sync up to discuss. Sound good?

Comment: I am sorry but both questions are different :) I did not miss anything neither the interviewer called at unscheduled time

Comment: @MaskedMan In addition to the points Faisal raised this question is about an informational interview which is quite a bit different from a normal interview.

Comment: I would avoid LinkedIn until further notice: http://www.businessinsider.com/linkedin-earnings-q4-2016-2

Comment: @JimG. The OP is asking about using LinkedIn, not buying stock in it, and it's not like the website is going to suddenly shut down without notice. That article is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @DavidK: I agree on both fronts. In a few minutes, this question will be closed as a duplicate and we'll forget all about it. In the meantime, it's Friday afternoon, and I was just trying to add a little levity to the situation.

Answer (score 0):

> Good morning Faisal! I enjoyed reading your email this morning and would like to offer up some time for us to chat. Let me know your availability and we can look to sync up to discuss. Sound good?

He/she might not remember who you were so a reminder that you a) met with him/her and b) you are following up on a meeting request.

I would write something like:

Hello Faisal, I met you earlier last week and you mentioned that you would like to meet. I am wondering if you are still interested? I am available anytime on X, Y, and Z. Please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Also remember that chances are this contact receives nearly hundreds of messages a day. I would reply on top of your last mail and say, "Hello, XXX - I imagine you are incredibly busy so i am sorry to bother you again, I was just so excited after our last exchange (include a reference) that i wanted to make sure we found a chance to meet if your schedule allowed. Thanks in advance - I look forward to meeting."

This way it balances pushiness with politeness, but shows your commitment, excitement and follow through.